# How can I enable standard camera throughout my app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to have controls from standard camera in my app.

With this code I not get it

```
imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

Comment: Your app is not the Camera app. If you want your app to be the Camera app you will effectively have to _write_ the Camera app (including the interface).

Comment: @matt, you mean that I want to have standard camera interface in my app, I need to create it from scratch as overlay?

Comment: Or you can write a _whole_ new interface using AVFoundation. That is, unless someone has reverse-engineered that code as a library or open source code you can download. But as far as Apple is concerned, what Apple gives you in UIImagePickerController, that's what they give you. Anything else is up to you.